# mySQL isn't giving the results that it should

Tags: mysql

I have been creating a data base for an assignment and I have a query that needs to be implemented.
The query needs to Provide a project id of all projects that have more than two update patches.
and I'm using the query:

```
SELECT projectID
FROM Transaction
HAVING COUNT(Transaction.status = ‘patch’) > 2
```

but I'm getting `projectID 1` from this eventhough the only project with more than two patches is 9.

I'm using the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Transaction
( 
    transactionID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    ProjectID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(transactionID, projectID),
    FOREIGN KEY(projectID) REFERENCES Project(projectID),
    userID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(userID) REFERENCES Developer(userID),
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    status ENUM('upload','update','patch') NOT NULL
);
```

and this is the data that I have in my table:

```
INSERT INTO Transaction
(transactionID, projectID, userID, date, status) values

(1,1,2,'2013-12-29','upload'),
(2,7,8,'2014-05-12','update'),
(3,9,20,'2013-07-15','patch'),
(4,12,8,'2013-08-04','upload'),
(5,10,26,'2014-11-06','update'),
(6,9,26,'2013-07-04','patch'),
(7,20,26,'2012-12-15','upload'),
(8,13,14,'2013-02-16','update'),
(9,12,8,'2014-07-11','patch'),
(10,19,20,'2013-08-14','upload'),
(11,19,20,2013-02-13,'update'),
(12,14,20,'2013-11-10','patch'),
(13,18,14,'2012-12-26','upload'),
(14,1,2,'2014-07-14','update'),
(15,12,8,'2013-04-11','patch'),
(16,3,14,'2013-09-16','upload'),
(17,4,20,'2013-09-02','update'),
(18,9,20,'2014-09-18','patch'),
(19,8,14,'2013-03-24','upload'),
(20,17,8,'2014-10-20','update');
```

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the group by clause

group by projectid

```
SELECT projectID
   FROM Transaction
   where Transaction.status = 'patch'
   group by projectid
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

Comment: Thanks it makes sense now, but one thing i dont understand is one of my friends has the exact same query and it worked perfectly fine for him

Comment: @Terakin, They probably had the group by clause.  But applying a WHERE clause will only process records based on that status and would be more optimized if you had an index on that column. Consider having a million records, 10 different status values resulting in avg 100k records each status.  The original would still blow through all million, but the where clause and an index would only blow through the 100k records.